# Показывается не там где надо

Tags: php, html, css

Вот мой index.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$f1="index.tpl";
if (!file_exists($f1)) {
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "<center>
<br><br>
<h1>Нет шаблона!</h1>
</center>";
exit;
}
$f = fopen($f1,"r"); 
$site = fread($f, filesize ($f1)); 
fclose ($f);
require_once "menu_admin.php";
$site=str_replace('{menu}',$menu,$site);
echo "{$site}";
exit;
?>
```

А вот index.tpl (шаблон)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>{TITLE}</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
<head>
<body class="thrColHybHdr">
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
<center>
    <img src="http://www.igodkb.ru/templates/IGODKBv3/images/logo.gif">
</center> 
  <!-- end #header --></div>
  <div id="menu">
  {menu}
  </div>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
    <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats --><br class="clearfloat" />
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Счетчики</p>
  <!-- end #footer --></div>
<!-- end #container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему мое меню показывается не там где нужно? В самом ввержу а не под шапкой?

Comment: Для начала отформатируйте код и поместите его в соответствующий контейнер. Проверьте css.

Comment: Да ведь вроде все отформатировано и все помещено. Или я не то подразумеваю?

Comment: дайте html-код сформированной страницы или ссылку на ваш проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меню не писалось в переменную $menu и в результате не срабатывала строка

```
$site=str_replace('{menu}',$menu,$site);
```

а менюшка просто писалась до шаблона.

Comment: тут уже смотреть нечего. у него был вызов меню <pre>require_once "menu_admin.php";
$site=str_replace('{menu}',$menu,$site);</pre>
а в файле меню все выводилось через echo""; вместо чтобы в переменную $menu. пришлось поставить ему в код вот это
<pre><?
$menu="";
ob_start();

// выписка менюшки;

$menu=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?></pre>